# Fundamental group of a kite shaped grid

Tags: algebraic-topology

What is the fundamental group of a "kite-shaped" two dimensional figure, with lines connecting opposite pairs of corner-points? (So, a diamond with a cross in the middle.)

Doesn't this just deformation retract to a wedge of 4 circles?

Comment: Yes, it does. Alternatively, you can calculate the Euler characteristic and use that to compute $H_1$ and hence $\pi_1$. This method is useful for more complicated graphs.

Comment: Ok. This was on my qualifier exam and I wanted to make sure I got the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it deformation retracts to a wedge of four circles. Additionally, $\pi_1(\bigvee^4 S^1)=\ast^4\pi_1(S^1)$, where $\ast$ is the free product of groups.